# how should i display java class file on jsp(web)

Tags: java, jsp

hi i am new in java i implement one java file which successfully run and gives me output.

i want ut to display it on a web. i guess with using jsp i can do it.

can anybody can help me for this

here is my file?

```
import java.io.File;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 

public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile{

    public static void main (String argv []){
    try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("book.xml"));

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
                 doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
            int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);

            for(int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength() ; s++){


                Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                if(firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;

                    //-------
                    NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("First Name : " + 
                           ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //-------
                    NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
                    Element lastNameElement = (Element)lastNameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("Last Name : " + 
                           ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //----
                    NodeList ageList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("age");
                    Element ageElement = (Element)ageList.item(0);

                    NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("Age : " + 
                           ((Node)textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    //------


                }//end of if clause


            }//end of for loop with s var


        }catch (SAXParseException err) {
        System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " 
             + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());

        }catch (SAXException e) {
        Exception x = e.getException ();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();

        }catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace ();
        }
        //System.exit (0);

    }//end of main


}
```

please help me how should i display this output on web?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PrintWriter` from `HttpServletResponse` class using the `getWriter()` method and use that object in place of `System.out` in your code, the XML will be written to the response...
in order to get hold of the `HttpServletResponse`, you need to create a `HttpServlet`, [google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20a%20servlet&safe=off) on how to do it.